# Is there a way to output valid Swift code to debugger?

Tags: swift, debugging, swiftui, encode, auto-generate

I'm attempting to write a function that would allow me to take any object (or, if required due to limitations, an object that conforms to a custom protocol) during runtime and output the object to the console *as a reconstituted Swift object* that I could copy and paste back into a Swift file and use that object in code.

The desire stems from wanting to easily create stub data (either for SwiftUI Previews or for testing or just for posterity).

Below is a simple example using a struct with the default memberwise initializer. But it would be amazing to figure out a solution for classes or custom initializers - but perhaps that is an impossible ask.

Pseudo Code Example:

```
struct Foo {
   var bar: String
}

func handle(foo: Foo) {
   printCode(foo)
}

func printCode<T>(t: T) {
   let swiftT = // code to magically convert T instance to Swift code
   debugPrint(swiftT)
}
```

And the output to the console would be:
`Foo(bar: "WooHoo!")`

Then I can avoid the tedious and error prone process of hand generating these models.

I tried creating a protocol the object must conform to and written a default implementation to output the code in a generic manner using reflection (mirror) but failed.

Another attempt I had the object conform to Encodable and then wrote a custom encoder to output code (again, using reflection) but also failed.

Ideally this would work on any object without needing to require any change to the object to enable the functionality.

This request seems feasible and could be useful for all manner of situations. I feel like I must be missing something or there's a simple tool or command that can just do this. (Clearly the debugger is able to recreate the object - I want to do the same thing, just as swift code!)

Comment: In the general case this isn't possible, because there's no promise of an `init` that can reconstruct the object at all. What would this output if you passed a UIViewController subclass (particularly one initialized by a XIB)? What would it print for a CBPeripheral? Even "pure data" types may have internal or fileprivate inits that cannot be called. Or may not have a full memberwise init. A straightforward approach is to create a protocol that requires Codable and provides a default `init(json: String)` and `.jsonString`. But being able to output Swift code doesn't mean it can run.

Comment: I would look at https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery as something that can write any tedious code for you, and keep watching the evolution of Swift macros, which may help you without external tools: https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-declaration-macros/62373

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `Mirror` could help you get what you want?

```
func printObject(_ object: Any) {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: object)
    
    let properties: String = mirror.children.compactMap { child in
        guard let label = child.label else { return nil }
        
        switch child.value {
        case is Int:
            return "\(label): Int = \(child.value)"
        case is String:
            return #"\#(label): String = "\#(child.value)""#
        default:
            return "\(label) = \(child.value)"
        }
        
        return "\(label): \(child.value)"
    }
    .joined(separator: ", ")
    
    print("\(mirror.displayStyle!) \(mirror.subjectType)(\(properties))")
}
```

Then with an object like:

```
class Foo {
    init(bar: String, baz: Int) {
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz
    }
    
    var bar: String
    var baz: Int
}
```

gives you

```
let foo = Foo(bar: "WhoHoo!", baz: 3)
printObject(foo)

// class Foo(bar: String = "WhoHoo!", baz: Int = 3)
```

Comment: This was not quite the output I was looking for but the work you did in `printObject` would get me there. Effectively, I want the the right side of your first line to be what is output: `Foo(bar: "WhoHoo!", baz: 3)`. I want a way to create the `Foo` instance during runtime so that I don't have to manually create the instance. Your example shows a way that could be done.